# KeyPress Function is delayed by a whole Step

Tags: vb.net, keypress, data-conversion

I am writing a program and one of its functions resides on this:

whenever a user inputs a key in a textbox, if the key can be converted to an integer, I want the value to be multiplied and then put into another textbox.

The problem I have with it is the timing of the process. When I input a key, say "1", the program doesn't convert it but when I put "12", the program calculates with "1" instead of "12".

Can you please help me? Thanks!

```
 Private Sub TextEdit1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextEdit1.KeyPress
    cambioCantImporte(TextEdit1, TextEdit2, LabelControl1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub cambioCantImporte(text1 As TextEdit, text2 As TextEdit, denominacion As String)
    Dim x = Double.Parse(denominacion)

    Try
        If CInt(text1.Text) < 0 Then Exit Sub
        Dim y = CInt(text1.Text)

        If x > 0 Then
            text2.Text = CType(x * y, String)
        Else
            text2.Text = CType(CInt(x / y), String)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        If text1.Text = "" Then
            text1.Text = "0"
            text2.Text = "0"
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: When you enter one character, does it fall into your catch? Have you tried debugging with breakpoints?

Comment: The KeyPress event fires *before* the character is added to the Text property.  It is not clear why you use the event at all.  Use the TextChanged event instead, it fires *after* the Text property changed.

Comment: @TylerRoper Yes, it did fall into the catch statement

Comment: @HansPassant And that fixed the problem, thanks!